# Non intersecting objects

Tags: sculpting

Is there a way to sculpt(while in sculpt mode) a separate object in a scene such that it conforms to the surface of another object without passing through that object? Essentially can another object act as a mask for sculpting a separate object?

[image: multi object sculpt issue]

[image: intersection problem]

Comment: Could you add some images illustrating what you mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can work around it with the shrinkwrap modifier. Make a vertex group with the part that you want your other object to touch. Add shrinkwrap. Set your other object as target. Select your vertex group. Apply. Sculpt the seam to make it not deformed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Gunslinger. I tried your workaround and it is viable with a possible disadvantage of the shrinkwrapped surface being susceptible to sculpt strokes while in dynotopo. Nonetheless a pretty easy workaround.

Comment: can you mask the vertex group so it does not move when you sculpt?

Comment: Couldn't use the sculpt mask tool as it does not appear to be available even after removing vertex group assignment used for shrinkwrap. Is there another masking tool that prevents sculpting input?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully anderstand your problem but here is an answer for masking out areas not to be sculpted. http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/3384/395

Comment: Thanks for the link. Success! I used the existing shrinkwrap vertex group assigned to the sculpt object, hid them and then sculpted away without affecting the shrinkwrapped surface. Wish the sculpt mask tool would work in this situation but this approach is quite functional. Thanks for your help.

Comment: OK, I am a fool as the sculpt mask tool does work fine in this case too. For some reason my GUI didn't display the tool as being available. Hit "M" key and it came back.

Answer (score 0):

Not currently. The only time the surface of two objects effect anything is during physics simulations, whether it is rigid bodies, cloth, particles, fluid or smoke, an object can be configured to collide with other simulated objects.

The closest feature to what you want is surface snapping used for re-topology but that snaps straight to the surface of another object rather than moving gradually until it hits the surface.

Comment: Thank you for your answer sambler. I am aware of surface snapping but was hoping to find a way to do what I want while in sculpt mode. Trying to set up a way for inexperienced users to sculpt muscles on bones without having to do too much with program other than sculpting.