# Masking selected vertices for sculpting

Tags: edit-mode, sculpting, shortcut, masking

I have 3 questions related to masking in blender. I'm using latest 2.80rc2.

1. Is there a way to mask a subobject or selected vertices inside a mesh?
2. Can we mask a selected vertex group?

For example, say I added a UV Sphere as eyeball and then I need to place the skin in relative to the eyeball without affecting it. Hiding eyeball sphere would be harder for visualizing the effect of sculpting.

Using mask brush to mask the eyeball would be tedious to do. But we could hit [L] key to select vertices of just the UV Sphere..

3. Can we use a feathering like mask with mask brush? If so, can we adjust the easing function with graph, just like in proportionate editing?

Comment: Related: [Masking for sculpting through edit mode](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3379/masking-for-sculpting-through-edit-mode?rq=1)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to do this. I'm using 2.93. First, select the vertices that you want to mask in edit mode. You can make them into a vertex group if you want to save the selection.

Go into sculpt mode, and go to Face Sets > Face Set from Edit Mode Selection. You should see the selected vertices change into a different color on your mesh. Now, if you hover over a face set on your mesh and press 'h', it will hide the rest of your mesh except for the face set you are hovering over. Hover your mouse over the face set that you want to mask, and press 'h'. You should now only see the part of your mesh that was selected.

Now to go to Mask > Fill Mask. It should fill the visible part of your mesh with a mask. Now you can unhide the rest of your mesh by hovering over your visible face set and pressing 'h' again. You should be able to sculpt everywhere now except for your selection.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding vertices.

There is a menu option ... Hide Vertices.
This Hides the current selection.

Vertex groups give a reusable name to vertices. In case you need to hide vertices repeatedly.

Comment: Thank you. I know about hide option. ([Shift]+[H] to hide selected vertices, [Alt]+[H] to show hidden vertices.) What I want to know is is there any 'mask' selected vertices option, which shows the masked vertices in dark gray and unaffected while sculpting.

Comment: I’m looking for the same thing. There is an addon available, but it has many features I do not want. Basically selecting a vertex group and then converting this into a mask, to protect it in dynotopo sculpting.