# For sculpting, any alternative way to quickly mask any complicated mesh?

Tags: mesh, sculpting, geometry, masking

In Sculpt mode, it is tedious to completely mask any complicated geometry. For example, let's mask the ears on the following model:
[image]

There are lots of areas which are not covered by the mask, for example:

[image]

[image]

It is time-consuming to mask the entire ears by constantly changing the view perspective.

A more efficient way is to use [the power of Face Sets](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/243005/121027). However, when I turn on Dyntopo and use the Simplify brush, my Face Sets all disappeared. It seems that I have to rebuild all my Face Sets again.

Is there any other efficient way to mask the entire ears or nose or eye sockets please?

Comment: why not increase the scale of the model to make it easier to sculpt?

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie thank you for the comment! However, I don't really understand what you mean. If you know any other way, please post your answer. BTW, increasing the size of the model may mess up my lighting setup. I am using Cycles to quickly check if my sculpt is good or not. If it is not good, then I return to the sculpt mode and re-sculpt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the *N panel > Tool*, you can disable the *Front Face Only* option and enable *Falloff > Projected*, it will paint through the ear:

[image]

You could also use the *Face Sets* brush with the same options, or hide the faces in *Edit* mode...